# The location of http.sys?

Tags: iis

Where is this 'http.sys' actually located in Windows?
I can't find it in any Windows folder.
Where is this 'http.sys' file?
Where do I need to look?
I tried to search 'http.sys' on Google, but I could not find the folder.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: reverse engineering/debugging...

Answer (score 8):

It's located at `system32\drivers\http.sys`.

Answer (score 2):

`Windows\system32\drivers\http.sys`

its available only with XP SP2 and later.

Answer (score 0):

it's locate under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` by name **http** but it's actually **http.sys** is kernel level layer of IIS, every request comes from client is first to **http.sys** and then it  make a queue of every request based on application pool register number.